Conductance of $AB$ the same as $BA$?
I have two markov transition matrix $A$ and $B$ (so both are $n\times n$ stochastic matrices with rows sum to 1), $A$ is reversible, $B$ is symmetric (so doubly stochastic) and block diagonal with same values in each block. I notice in my simulations that the conductances of both $AB$ and $BA$ are the same. Not sure if this is true in general? I tried to show this but couldn't...
Here's the definition of conductance (bottleneck ratio) for a transition kernel $P$ with stationary distribution $\pi$.
The edge measure $Q$ is defined by
$$
Q(x, y):=\pi(x) P(x, y), \quad Q(A, B)=\sum_{x \in A, y \in B} Q(x, y) .
$$
The probability flow from the set $S$ to $S^c$ is defined to be
$$
\Phi(S):=\frac{Q\left(S, S^c\right)}{\pi(S)},
$$
while the conductance is
$$
\Phi_{\star}:=\min _{S: \pi(S) \leq \frac{1}{2}} \Phi(S)
$$
